# Ubuntu / SQL Server - PHP script works in terminal, but not web application

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, nginx, pdo

I have an Ubuntu VM / Azure SQL DB combo where I have two sets of PHP files.

1) Some scripts that run from CRON jobs

2) A Yii2 Framework website

Both environments connect to an SQL Server database.

I have done all the steps to compile sqlsrv and added it to PHP's list of extensions. My scripts work great from the terminal, but on the website, I get an error:

> could not find driver

My webserver is nginx, and it runs the website properly, but PDO does not connect to SQL Server.

I only have one PHP installation, but nevertheless used code to determine which is the right php.ini file in use and it has the right extensions directive.

A phpinfo() output also shows sqlsrv in the 'Registered PHP Streams' section.

My UFW firewall is inactive and I don't have SUSELinux. Nevertheless ports 22 and 80 are open. Even tried enabling it.

I am not sure what else to try. Help!

**EDIT**

I created a simple test file. When I run that through the terminal, it works, but when I do so via a browser, it doesn't.

**EDIT 2**

I installed Apache2 instead of nginx, and everything works now.

Comment: Can you double check to see if your DSN string is the exact same in both the cron job scripts and web app? The DSN is the first argument to the PDO constructor: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-parameters. You might have this in your Yii config: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-databases#configuring-db-connection

Comment: @IanDrake I copy pasted the DSN string from my script files to the Yii Framework, and also to a blank test.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try with just some "Hello world". If this not help type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

And restart your nginx server with:

```
sudo killall nginx && /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: I have a three line hello world program and I am using nginx / sql server